# Foreman conditional process with .env file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, foreman

I am using foreman gem on my Ruby on Rails application to launch my different processes.
In a .env file, I declared some boolean variable to decide if I want to run a process or not.

I want to be able to enable or disabled « maildev », a nodejs application to handle email in local. If the boolean is true it’s working perfectly but if change it to false, foreman crash on startup.

**Here is the trace from foreman**:

```
13:20:17 web.1    | started with pid 6583
13:20:17 mailer.1 | started with pid 6584
13:20:17 mailer.1 | ====== Maildev server not launched ======
13:20:17 mailer.1 | exited with code 0
13:20:17 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
13:20:17 web.1    | terminated by SIGTERM
```

**my .env file**:

```
RACK_ENV=development
START_MAILDEV=false
```

**my Procfile**:

```
# Rails server
web: bin/procfile/web

# Mail server
mailer: bin/procfile/maildev
```

**bin/procfile/maildev**:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ "$RACK_ENV" == 'development' ]]; then
  if [[ "$START_MAILDEV" == "true" ]]; then
    maildev
    echo "====== Maildev server launched ======"
  else
    echo "====== Maildev server not launched ======"
  fi
fi
```

Does someone know what’s wrong with my code ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, but when one of your processes exits, which `echo` does immediately, Foreman shuts down all the rest of them.

Foreman's approved way to run only some processes is with [the `-c` flag](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/).

> **-c, --concurrency**
>
> Specify the number of each process type to run. The value passed in should be in the format **process=num,process=num**

In your case,

```
foreman start -c web=1
```

If you have lots of processes and you want to run them all *except* for one, there's a special `all` keyword, and then you can override the one you don't want.

```
foreman start -c all=1,maildev=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! I will use this command now even if I would have preferred to just run `foreman start` and let the file to handle the conditions